# (HTML) How to move navbar at edge left side

Tags: html, css, navbar

I am new to html/css and I am trying to edit a landing page. I almost got it I only have one problem that I can't seem to find how to do.

I want to move this navbar at the very edge left side of my website:
[image]

I think I need to insert something in this codes but just don't know what it is.

```html
ul {
 float: left;
 margin: 30px 0 50px 0;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 border-radius: 10px;
 list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #010c15;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    border-radius: 10px;
 background-color: #0099ff;
    color: white;
}
```

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: please post your HTML source too..

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the following:

```
ul{
  position:absolute;
  left: 0;
  ....
}
```

Also you seem to have `margin` listed twice

Answer (score 0):

You can use that :

```
  ul {
     position:absolute;
     left: 0px;
     top: 0px;
     ....
   }
```

For ref: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp